# Create methods with the same function like new and edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can somebody tell me please how can I create and configure in routes.rb some anothers methods with the same function like new and like edit called like that for the model "caracterizaciones"

```
def paso1

end

def paso2

end

def edit_paso1    
end

def edit_paso2    
end
```

That's because I need to create like a wizard in 1 model with 5 files filling the information step by step

For example when I want to edit a record the url is like that

```
localhost:3000/caracterizaciones/1/edit
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add actions to your resource within the routes.rb file

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-member

```
resources :caracterizaciones do
  # for particular record e.g /caracterizaciones/1/foo
  member do
    get :foo
    post :bar
  end

  # for no given record e.g /caracterizaciones/foo
  collection do
    get :foo
    post :bar
  end
end
```

But, you might also want to break these additional actions into separate controller, instead.